# Constructing filters from list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to construct a series of and filters and I got

> ValueError("Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.")

```py
filters = None
for desc in tabu_list:
    f = ~col("col1").rlike(desc)
    filters = (filters) & (f) if filters else f  # exception throw

df = df.filter(filters)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `if filters is not None` as the check, otherwise `if filters` will attempt to cast the column into a Boolean and causes an error:

```
filters = None
for desc in tabu_list:
    f = ~F.col("col1").rlike(desc)
    filters = filters & f if filters is not None else f
```

Alternatively, use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

func = lambda c: ~F.col("col1").rlike(c)
filters = reduce(lambda x, y: x & func(y), tabu_list[1:], func(tabu_list[0]))
```